# Can anyone explain why I am getting this error: Error in seq_len(n - i) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer

Tags: time-series

[ERROR in Seasonality test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgSIk.png)

[MYTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpIWs.png)

I am doing time series model for daily data, from 1998 jan to june.
while running seasonal test, I am getting this error;

```
ch.test(myts, sid= 7)
```

The message appeared:

```
Error in seq_len(n - i) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
6.
NextMethod("[")
5.
`[.ts`(SDe, seq_len(n - i), , drop = FALSE)
4.
SDe[seq_len(n - i), , drop = FALSE]
3.
crossprod(SDe[seq_len(n - i), , drop = FALSE], SDe[-seq_len(i), , drop = FALSE])
2.
ch.test0(id)
1.
ch.test(myts, sid = 7)
```

Comment: Can you show what is the `myts`?

Comment: Posted the picture of myts and full error also